# Using the !== Operator to compare strings taken froma Dropdown list - Javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

I'm trying to get q1check to read a value from the dropdown form item 'qq1'.'
It's reading it in fine.
There seems to be an issue with the way I'm using the comparison operators.
Could anyone help me?

```
function q1ans_check(){
    var q1check = document.getElementById("qq1").value;
    alert(q1check);
    if(q1check !== "1" || qlcheck !=="0")
    {
        alert("Please answer Question 1");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `!==` is fine. The problem is with your use of `||` instead of `&&`. There's also a typo — you misspelled "q1check" in the second comparison.

The test in the `if` statement:

```
if(q1check !== "1" || q1check !=="0")
```

(assuming you fix the typo like I did) will *always* be `true`. In English, that means, "If q1check is not equal to the string `"1"` **or** if q1check is not equal to the string `"0"`, then ...".  If the variable is neither `"1"` nor `"0"`, then it's `true`.  If it's `"1"`, then the test is `true` because it's therefore not `"0"`. If it *is* `"0"`, then the test is `true` because it's not `"1"`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure. I have two options for q1check. If it is either 1 or 0 it should not display the message. I assuming with the && operator, it will be looking for both values.

Comment: Wonderful! It worked! Thank you so much! Thanks for helping me! Sorry for doubting.